# PHP Query not Outputting into a Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

So I have a query that is pulling most the info from a mysql db apart from one or two fields. I want to output the data into a table but I have been struggling due to the way the data is outputting line by line to incorporate html table tags. Some friends suggested using CSS to style borders around the various columns but I don't want to use set width css borders to make a table.

Any assistance would be great so far any attempt to echo a table after the "while" causes a 1px x 1px table between every line of data.

```
 <?php  include 'database_conn.php';      // make db connection

    $sql = "SELECT CDID, CDTitle, CDYear, catID, CDPrice FROM `nmc_cd` ORDER BY `nmc_cd`.`CDTitle` ASC";

        $rsCD = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsCD)) {
            $CDID = $row['CDID'];
                $CDTitle = $row['CDTitle'];
                $CDYear = $row['CDYear']; 
                $catID = $row['catID'];
              $CDPrice = $row['CDPrice']; 

        echo "<br>";
        echo "<span class= \"CDID\">$CDID</span>\n";
        echo "<span class= \"CDTitle\">$CDTitle</span>\n";
        echo "<span class= \"CDYear\">$CDYear</span>\n"; 
        echo "<span class= \"catID\">$catID</span>\n";  
        echo "<span class= \"CDPrice\">$CDPrice</span>\n";  
        echo "</div>\n";

            }   mysqli_free_result($rsCD); 
          mysqli_close($conn); ?>
```

- UPDATE CLARIFICATION *Tried a few different methods one of which is below.

  ```
  $sql = "SELECT CDID, CDTitle, CDYear, catID, CDPrice FROM `nmc_cd` ORDER BY `nmc_cd`.`CDTitle` ASC";

      $rsCD = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsCD)) {
          $CDID = $row['CDID'];
              $CDTitle = $row['CDTitle'];
              $CDYear = $row['CDYear']; 
              $catID = $row['catID'];
            $CDPrice = $row['CDPrice']; 

            echo "<table id='dattabletho'>";
          echo"<tr>";
      echo "<td><span class= \'CDID\'> " . $CDID . "</span>\n";
      echo "<td><span class= \'CDTitle\'> " . $CDTitle . "</span></td>\n";
      echo "<td><span class= \'CDYear\'> " . $CDYear . "</span></td>\n"; 
      echo "<td><span class= \'catID\'> " . $catID . "</span></td>\n";  
      echo "<td><span class= \'CDPrice\'> " . $CDPrice . "</span></td>\n";  
          echo"</tr>";

          }   
          echo "</table>";
          mysqli_free_result($rsCD); 
        mysqli_close($conn); ?>
  ```

With the above code I have managed to get each line outputting as a joint row, I am trying to get the data from my query into a table not output a simple empty table. The reason this is difficult is because I need several records that are being retrieved to be on the same row and preferably aligned columns in the table. I am aware this is just as much a HTML question as PHP question I am quite new to PHP / SQL.

Comment: `not Outputting into a Table` where is your table..?? why cant you put in `<table></table>`..?

Comment: What i understood from your question is that u don't want to use CSS and still want a bordered table but i dont even see a table in your code?

Comment: I've updated my post to clarify what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php  include 'database_conn.php';      // make db connection

    $sql = "SELECT CDID, CDTitle, CDYear, catID, CDPrice FROM `nmc_cd` ORDER BY `nmc_cd`.`CDTitle` ASC";

        $rsCD = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsCD)) {
            $CDID = $row['CDID'];
                $CDTitle = $row['CDTitle'];
                $CDYear = $row['CDYear']; 
                $catID = $row['catID'];
              $CDPrice = $row['CDPrice']; 

        echo "<br>";
        echo "<span class= \'CDID\'> " . $CDID . "</span>\n";
        echo "<span class= \'CDTitle\'> " . $CDTitle . "</span>\n";
        echo "<span class= \'CDYear\'> " . $CDYear . "</span>\n"; 
        echo "<span class= \'catID\'> " . $catID . "</span>\n";  
        echo "<span class= \'CDPrice\'> " . $CDPrice . "</span>\n";  
        echo "</div>\n";

            }   mysqli_free_result($rsCD); 
          mysqli_close($conn); ?>
```

Comment: what is the difference..??

Comment: concatenation of php variables to print them

Comment: echo "<span class= \"CDID\">$CDID</span>\n";

here also double quotes inside the double quotes which breaks rule.

Comment: using the a backslash \ before " nulls this though, making it acceptable. Does using the dot operator allow me to put the output into a table compared to the " ?

Comment: it was escaped with \ so its fine.  double-quoted strings have variable interpolation So `"my name is $name"` and `"my name is".$name` are the same

Comment: @Wiper Yes, that should be fine. One tip: HTML attributes can use either single or double quotes, so \echo "span class='CDID'>$CDID</span>\n" will also work fine. I find that approach a bit more readable sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

First we have include config file means we have  connect database

```
$query="select * from city";
$res = mysql_query($query);
while($data=mysql_fetch_array(res)){
$data['city_name']."<br>";

}
```

Comment: "" include 'database_conn.php';      // make db connection ""

I have a script for this I'm connecting fine I don't even know why you have quoted this code from a different script